# When do we use contextfilter decorator of Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

Jinja2 has an utilities named [contextfilter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.contextfilter).

I cannot find any document about this filter in Jinja2 site
Can anyone help me to explain when we use this function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It says right there on the page that it is a decorator for marking context dependent filters. I guess it is used to limit a dimensional report to the context of a particular member of a hierarchy. I hope this answers your question.